# How to write an xpath for getting more colors in an web page

Tags: xpath

**How to write an x path for getting more colors in an web page**
**(for  example)This is the web page I am getting two color,for this I need to know how can identify through x path.**
(http://www.flipkart.com/comfort-boxer-black-casual-shoes/p/itme84ykdubkghkm?pid=SHOE84YKXF7MXMMK&&sizeSelected=true&otracker=pp_shoe_size )from this page.

Comment: What sort of things have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Below code work for me:-

```
driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/comfort-boxer-black-casual-shoes/p/itme84ykdubkghkm?pid=SHOE84YKXF7MXMMK&&sizeSelected=true&otracker=pp_shoe_size");

driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

List<WebElement> allOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='big selector-paletteImage']"));

System.out.println("Count of colour ="+allOptions.size());

for ( WebElement we: allOptions) { 
    System.out.println(we.getAttribute("data-selectorvalue"));
}
```